# Error writing content through Apache

Tags: apache

I am streaming out data (sometimes png, sometimes json, sometimes xml) and I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Error 321 (net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING): Unknown error.
```

I do not get this error when apache is not in front of my *Tomcat web application* (servlet), only when I deploy it to our test environment which has apache running.

Comment: In Safari I get:  kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303

Comment: Here are the returned headers:

Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 18 Jun 2010 20:28:46 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1, Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked, chunked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this question, I'm going to put the answer here:

The header entry:

```
Transfer-Encoding:chunked, chunked
```

was causing this error when the response was returned through Apache.  Without Apache in front everything worked fine.

Should be:
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: Sorry, the fix was to make the Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: I am facing exact same issue. Using apache. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry @JP19 just saw this, did you figure it out?

Comment: Sorry, but where should I change the Transfer-Encoding header? I really don't know where that is set.

Comment: As far as where this is set within your code you have to find that yourself.  I was setting it within my application code twice and my api added the value twice.

Comment: Oh, so it is a header sent by tomcat back to Apache. I had it all wrong. Well, I guess the container is doing it for me, will investigate it where and when.

Comment: This was 4 years ago, but if I recall, yes you're correct.